# What is the difference between さて、昼にしましょう and さて、昼をしましょう

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between:

「さて、昼**に**しましょう。」

and

「さて、昼**を**しましょう」。?

Comment: Are you asking this question knowing what the common set phrase 「（お）昼にする」 means?  If so, the particle cannot be changed.  See #3 here: https://jisho.org/search/%E6%98%BC

Answer (score 1):

...にする is a set expression indicating a choice one has/will make.

> さて、昼にしましょう

> Well, how about lunch?

---

There was a time when saying  things like *let's do lunch* or *let's do dinner* were viewed as horrible California-isms.  It seems they've managed to have established themselves more broadly in English now.

But, in Japanese, saying

> 昼をしましょう

while this is technically *grammatical,* as pointed out in the other answer, it doesn't make much sense.  (I was perhaps a bit careless in my use of the word, *grammatical*, previously.)  昼 here is being treated as the object of the verb する; you don't do *afternoon* in Japanese (even if you can make some kind of sense of that expression in English).

Comment: so, can お昼にしましょう translate to "lets decide to have lunch" ? @a-ellett

Comment: @yutrewq I would think that would depend on what you're talking about.  Without context, it just sounds like making a plan for "something" and deciding on *it* being in the afternoon (whatever "it" may be).

Comment: `さて、昼にしましょう Well, how about afternoon?` -- ん...？　This「昼」 is short for 昼ごはん, right? eg 「そろそろ食事にしましょう。」「晩ご飯にしよう。」「メシにするか。」(But not 「朝にしましょう」「夜にしましょう」 for "Let's have/start breakfast/dinner")

Answer (score 1):

昼をしましょう would mean "Let's do noon", but not in the sense of "do" meaning "choose" as it can in English.  And, "noon" is not something you can actively do or perform.  Like, you can't use it as an answer to questions like "What do you like to do?" or "What should we do together?"

So this doesn't make sense (though, contrary to above, it ***is*** grammatical).

Answer (score 1):

昼にする is a fixed phrase, but if you need to analyze it, I think you could see it as a special case of `ＡをＢにする` as follows.

> （この時間を）昼（ご飯を食べる時間）にする。

By the way, コーヒーにする could be seen like that, too.

> （私が飲むものを）コーヒーにする。

昼をする makes little sense. 昼 in the sense of either “daytime” or “lunch” simply doesn’t work well as an object of the verb する.

Comment: How to say "to have lunch" in the neutral sense then? Is 昼する ok?

Comment: @starckman - 昼ご飯を食べる